# text file line data is not splitting in node js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, split

I have following data in a text file

```
smtp.office365.com  587 1   hsgs@jsjsi.com  JaHi001!        110 hsgs@jsjsi.com  2   20  0   0   0   100000  2   1
smtp.office365.com  587 1   kksi@kkjh.co.ke Tajso1708       110 kksi@kkjh.co.ke 2   20  0   0   0   100000  2   1
smtp.office365.com  587 1   isus@isus.com   akm-129-1708        110 isus@isus.com   2   20  0   0   0   100000  2   1
```

i am using fs module to read file and readline to read it line by line

**Reading data from file is working fine**

```
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');
let rl = readline.createInterface({
                    input: fs.createReadStream('./public/uploads/logs.txt')
                });

                // event is emitted after each line
                rl.on('line', function(line) {
                  var ln = line.split("\\t")
                    console.log(ln);
                });

                // end
                rl.on('close', function(line) {
                   console.log('end');
                });
```

I'm heaving issue in splitting the line on basis of ("\t")
**it is returning**

```
[ 'smtp.office365.com\t587\t1\hsgs@jsjsi.com\tJaHi001!\t\t110\thsgs@jsjsi.com\t2\t20\t0\t0\t0\t100000\t2\t1' ]
```

from this string in array i can not get the desired data i want please suggest a solution

if the string splits in array then i want to extract 4th and 5th index of string

Answer (score 0):

You need to split on `"\t"`, not on `"\\t"`.